# Transform ros2 bag to .mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, ros2

I am trying to transform a ROS2 bag into a .mat file in matlab to be able to run a simulation using these data in matlab.

I found `ros2bagreader` this function in matlab documentation which reada a ROS2 bag, but I could not find the format of the returned variable.

So I want to ask if this specific function returns a `.mat` file which then I will be able to import in a matlab function and use it's data to run a simulation.

Thanks!